# getting checkbox value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a checkbox below in a view page:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td> 
            <% @user_profession.each do |p| %>
            <% if !p.Designation.blank? and p.Private? == "1" %>
            <%= check_box(:ChkBx_Profession, {:id => "ChkBx_Profession",:value => "Profession"},true) %>
            <%= label(:lb_Profession, "Profession") %>
            <% else %>
            <%= check_box(:ChkBx_Profession,{:id => "ChkBx_Profession",:value => "Profession"}) %>
            <%= label(:lb_Profession, "Profession") %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
         </td> 
      </tr>
</table>
```

Below is my controller page

```
if params[:ChkBx_Profession] == "1"
    @blah = params[:ChkBx_Profession]
    @publicprofession = params[:ChkBx_Profession]
    Profession.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)
    if !params[:tf_designation].blank?
        @desig = params[:tf_designation]
        @comp = params[:tf_company]
        @fromdesigcom = params[:tf_fromdesignation]
        @todesigcom = params[:tf_todesignation]
        @public_profession = @publicprofession
        @Profession = Profession.new( :UserID => current_user.id, :Designation => @desig, :Company => @comp, :Job_From => @fromdesigcom, :Job_To => @todesigcom, :Private? => @publicprofession )
        @Profession.save
    end
end
```

and I want to get the checkbox value means if checkbox is checked it gets me 1 and if checkbox is unchecked it gets me 0 but its get like this `{"{:id=>\"ChkBx_Profession\", :value=>\"Profession\"}"=>"1"}`. Kindly help me waiting for your reply. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second attribute on an check_box is the :value attribute. Try putting empty double quotes between the chec_box name AND the options:

```
<%= check_box(:YourCheckName, "",{Your Options}) %>
```